# What dual function CAFCI+GFCI breaker fits an older Murray Breaker Box?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a LC240PC Murray breaker box (probably around year 1995).

I found what I believe is the breaker I'm looking for here:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Murray-20-Amp-AFCI-GFCI-Dual-Function-Circuit-Breaker-MP120DFP/205488021

But that one is discontinued and it says the replacement is this:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-20-Amp-1-Pole-Dual-Function-CAFCI-GFCI-Plug-On-Neutral-Circuit-Breaker-Q120DFNP/312276201

However, the correct one (first link) has a pigtail to plug into the neutral bar, and the replacement one (second link) does not (it says it is for "Plug On load centers".  I believe that my box is not the Plug-On style, so I would need the pigtail.

Is there a different replacement breaker (Dual function CAFCI+GFCI)that is still an active product that has the pigtail?

Comment: You're correct that you need the pigtail.  Home Depot's site is wrong, which happens all the time.  The right breaker is definitely made, and a more competent shop will help you find it.  Other than that, shopping/procurement questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need the pigtail neutral version of what you're looking at

Your problem is that Home Depot sent you off to the Plug-on Neutral (N suffix) version of the Q120DF, which isn't compatible with older panels.  Instead, you need the plain Q120DF(P), which has a neutral pigtail on it and is compatible with your panel.

Answer (score 1):

PON (Plug On Neutral) panels are a relatively new development. Given the date of your panel there's virtually no chance its a PON panel. You'll need to find a breaker with a pigtail.